# Pause Thread While Another Thread Is Executing A Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I created a Thread that executes a task, but i need to pause my Main thread until my secondary threads ends the task.

```
    private void AquilesPL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(RunTask)
       Thread t = new Thread(ts);
       t.Start();
       SomeFunction1();
       SomeFunction2();
       //I need to pause the main thread here, if runtask() continue working
       //if runt task ends, this main thread must to continue.
       ReadFile();
       CloseProgram();
    }
    private void RunTask()
    {
        //Some code that write a file 
        //RunTaskfunction ends, and i have to continue 
    }

    private void ReadFile()
    {
        //Reading the file, this file has been written by RunTask

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The EventArgs is an indicator you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What C# / .NET version are you using or can you use? What's the type of the application (WinForms?)?

Comment: You never "pause" the main thread of a GUI app.  That doesn't accomplish anything but deadlock or a non-functional frozen user interface.  Use the Enabled property of controls to prevent them from being used while work is being done.  A dialog that indicates progress is an obvious choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but i need to pause my Main thread until my secondary threads ends the task.

This is typically a bad idea.  A better solution is to disable the UI while the task is executing, then re-enable it when it's completed.

The TPL and async/await make this fairly straightforward.  For example:

```
private async void AquilesPL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var task = Task.Run(() => RunTask());
   SomeFunction1();
   SomeFunction2();

   // Disable your UI controls

   await task; // This will wait until the task completes, 
               // but do it asynchronously so it does not block the UI thread

   // This won't read until the other task is done
   ReadFile();

   // Enable your UI controls here
}
```

If you can't use C# 5, you can do this via .NET 4 and the TPL:

```
private void AquilesPL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunTask());

   SomeFunction1();
   SomeFunction2();

   // Disable your UI controls

   task.ContinueWith(t =>
   {
       // This won't read until the other task is done
       ReadFile();

       // Enable your UI controls here
   }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: I was about to write the same answer, so +1

Comment: The words "will block" might convey a wrong and conflicting message here. And not all WinForms users are (able to) use C#5.

Comment: Great. It seems the OP will need the 2nd part of the answer.

Comment: RunTask process runs an antivirusscaner, and collects information from the antivirus logs, it needs 1 or 3 minutes. It possible Runtask ends first than others.

Comment: That's relevant information, add (edit) it to the question. But it doesn't conflict with this answer.

Comment: @WitcacyMartinez That's fine - this will work whether it's 3 seconds or 30 minutes...

Comment: With a timer or a counter i will handle if elpased time its grater than 2 minutes...